"could have been, had not" - am I understaning it correctly in context?

There could have been no survivors within miles, had not the other bombers continued to plow their fields with the fires of hell.

That one is difficult for me for understand. I suspect it is incorrect in expressing the idea of the writer.
If "could have been no survivors" + "had something", then something not happened and there were survivors. Now if "had not something", then the literal meaning that there were survivors because of more bombs, which is strange. Text around that quoted part gives no clue as to how fires have saved, just the opposite.

You're quite correct - the cited text is oxymoronic nonsense. Probably penned by someone who thinks he has better command of English than is actually the case, and is trying to use formal literary constructions beyond his competence.

I’m voting to close this question because it's just asking for confirmation that pretentious drivel is what it is

@FumbleFingers I'd suggest posting that first comment as an answer.

Where did this come from, and what are the surrounding sentences?

I think it's such a trivial / pointless question it wouldn't even pass muster on English Language Learners, let alone a site aimed at linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.

@FumbleFingers, it is from a best selling modern author, one can make occasional mistakes if one writes many long books. Do you advise I delete the question?

Given Thomas Pynchon may consider this overwritten, calling it pointless is a bit narrow. Some valid context may exist, no matter how contrived. Additional context would clarify.

"from a best selling modern author"? But you haven't provided a link to a source. Perhaps a typo?

The actual meaning of the sentence is:

If the other bombers had not continued to plow their fields with the fires of hell, there could have been no survivors.

You are correct that this seems unlikely to be what the author intended, but it is what they wrote. It makes grammatical sense but seems illogical. Conceivably the bombers actions had preventing someone from killing off the remaining survivors, but a language error seems more likely.

You've got 'could not possibly' for 'could not', but 'There could have been no survivors within miles' might mean ''There might have been no survivors within miles'.

Good point. Fixed.
